# How to use AD-integrated DNS to serve records for two unrelated domains

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

I have a stand-alone active directory forest that's not on the internet at all.  I want to know if it's possible to create a second lookup zone in DNS that serves DNS records for a second domain, or if I need to actually create a full-up second domain in order to do so.

Every method I've tried winds up appending my new domain name to the other one for the FQDN.

To be clear, I want my AD DNS to serve records for both:

example.com and 
myOtherExample.com

but I don't want myOtherExample.com to be a subdomain in the DNS tree.  Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is entirely doable.

1. Open DNS Manager
2. Expand Forward Lookup Zones
3. Right click on Forward Lookup ZOnes and select New Zone
4. In the wizard select "Primary Zone" and make sure the "Store the zone in Active Directory" checkbox is checked.
5. Allow it to replicate to all the DNS servers in the AD Domain (or Forest if you want to)
6. Give it a name
7. Configure dynamic update security
8. Done.

That will create a forward lookup DNS zone for the DNS domain you create.

Comment: Yeah, I actually figured it out.  I'd been doing Secondary Lookup Zone, thinking that it's a 'secondary domain'.  Thanks, though, and you get the answer of course.

Comment: @Paul: a secondary domain is for traditional DNS systems where you want a DNS server to pull the domain zone information from another server which is designated the 'primary' or 'authoritative' server.